# PHP mysql query returns a blank screen

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've commented out the bottom part, and the SQL query works fine. Its the displaying of the query where the error is coming from i believe.

```
$host = "127.0.0.1"; 
$user = "root"; 
$pass = "Toom13371!";

$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_errno().":     ".mysql_error()."<BR>");

// 2. Selecting DB.

$dbname = "filters"; 
mysql_select_db($dbname);

// 3. Build/Test SQL Query

$sql = ("select * from filter_bandpass where start_passband=" . $_POST['Lowfreq'] . "         and stop_passband='" . $_POST['Highfreq'] . "'");
//echo $sql; //Comment/Uncomment to test sql query.

// 4. Retrieve info from MySQL.

$query = mysql_query($sql);

// 5. Display Query.

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Low Frequency</th>
<th>High Frequency</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Lowfreq'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Highfreq'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
  ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure it's going to be some small stupid error i've over looked.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? `$_POST` data should **NEVER** go directly into a query. `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! Will look into PDO.

Comment: @thomasward1212 - It is good practice on stackoverflow to accept an answer from given answers. Please select an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing, based on your query, that you need to change this

```
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

to

```
mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);
```

and

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Lowfreq'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Highfreq'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

to

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['start_passband'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['stop_passband'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: What i'm getting now is the top part of the table, this bit;
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Low Frequency</th>
<th>High Frequency</th>
</tr>";

But not the query generated part.

Answer (score 0):

Change line

```
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

to

```
mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);
```

Also before query check

`$_POST['Lowfreq']` and `$_POST['Highfreq']`

If there is no value in these variables query will must return empty.

Answer (score 0):

In your query there should not brackets for string.

```
 $sql = ("select * from filter_bandpass where start_passband=" . $_POST['Lowfreq'] . "         and stop_passband='" . $_POST['Highfreq'] . "'");
```

should be:

```
 $sql = "select * from filter_bandpass where start_passband=" . $_POST['Lowfreq'] . "         and stop_passband='" . $_POST['Highfreq'] . "'";
```